# Invalid Cast Exception was unhandled

Tags: c#, datagridview

i want to try call an event inside a function and the event that i want to call is `DataGridViewCellEventArgs`, but it is inside a function. But, when i tried below code, i got this error: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs'.`

Here is the code:

```
private void UpdateQuantityDataGridView(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           (...Other codes)
           var _productCode = dataGridView1["Product Code", ((DataGridViewCellEventArgs)e).RowIndex].Value;
           (...Other codes)

        }
```

I call above function when the user finish editing the data in `DataGridView` and press "OK" button, the function above is to update any changes that has been made by user to the Database as well as in DataGridView

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast `EventArgs(parent type)` to  `DataGridViewCellEventArgs(child type)`. This is not safe at this scenario. You can create a new `DataGridViewCellEventArgs`.

```
var _productCode = dataGridView1["Product Code",(new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(columnIndex, rowIndex)).RowIndex].Value;
```

Here a new `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` is created. Since it is a Event argument for a cell related action a `columnIndex` and `rowIndex` is needed to locate the cell.

Comment: what is colIndex and rowIndex sir?